# Handle blank value in Complex expression IF condition in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am writing a calculated column of the form

Column = IF( ISBLANK(ComplexExpression),0, ComplexExpression)

Does PowerBi recompute ComplexExpression twice?

Comment: I'm not sure if the expression is computed twice, but I hope DAX is smart enough to not do so!

I believe what you are doing is the most straightforward way to handle blanks in DAX. I'm not a big fan of it either, because I don't like having to type out complex expressions twice as well.

What I'd recommend is you create a column with your ComplexExpression first, and then create a 2nd column which uses this formula with a reference to the 1st column.

Comment: Currently doing this. @RedVII.
I am trying to understand if DAX does some query optimization like SQL

Answer (score 0):

It seems the expression is not computed twice, if the conditional is evaluated to `True` only the true branch expression will be evaluated.

You can test it by doing two nested `IFs`.

```
NewColumn =
IF(
  [MyColumn]=1,
  4/2,
  1/IF([MyColumn]<>1,1,"A")
)
```

In the above expression, the outer `IF` conditional is evaluated and if it is true, the result is 2 (`4/2`), so the false branch expression is not evaluated since it produces a `#ERROR` because it evaluates to `1/"A"` which is undetermined.

```
MyColumn    NewColumn  
   1            2    --> If the false branch would be evaluated it'd produce an #ERROR
   2            1
   3            1
   1            2    --> If the false branch would be evaluated it'd produce an #ERROR
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I am looking for a different answer. Is the expression computed twice if the outer IF is false [once while checking the outer IF, and once while actually providing the value] , or does it cache the value in some sense?